# Can anyone help me? This is the answer 'process not defined' when executing Cypress test

Tags: testing, cypress

Trying to execute any of the tests leads to this error popping up.

The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> process is not defined

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHmPi.png)

And also the Stacktrace

> at Object../node_modules/ci-info/index.js (webpack:///./node_modules/ci-info/index.js:5:1)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Object../node_modules/is-ci/index.js (webpack:///./node_modules/is-ci/index.js:3:18)
> at **webpack_require** (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Object.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js:21:14)
> at Object../node_modules/cypress/lib/util.js ([https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\index.js:85591:31](https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Csupport%5Cindex.js:85591:31))
> at **webpack_require** (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
> at Object.eval (webpack:///./node_modules/cypress/index.js:9:14)
> at Object../node_modules/cypress/index.js ([https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/tests?p=cypress\support\index.js:81163:31](https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Csupport%5Cindex.js:81163:31))
> at **webpack_require** (webpack:///webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
>
> From previous event:
>
> at runScriptsFromUrls (https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160126:98)
> at Object.runScripts (https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:160140:11)
> at $Cypress.onSpecWindow (https://conciliador-hti.getnet.com.br/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:149554:19)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
Just in commands.js

My command was inserted with two mistakes:

cypress.Command.add

**cypress** instead Cypress - and - **Command** instead Commands.